# npm websocket - on request - message object

Tags: node.js, websocket

Where can I find in  details the properties of the message object?

I am talking about this object:

[image]

I wasnt able to find more information in the official page, nor googling it.
I see that it has properties: **type, utf8Data** but what else? And what is their meaning?

Comment: It depends on your frontend what your are trying to send either json object or text or something else , basically it contains type and user message.

Comment: that depends on what package you use to send and receive websocket message. Also you already have the code, why don't log the message and check yourself?